# GSuite Mail Enterprise, forwarding inbound mail from outside Enterprise

Tags: gmail, google-workspace-for-business, g-suite-administrator

As a GSuite Administrator, is there a way for me to forward all messages coming from a user **outside of my Enterprise** to a specific user **inside my Enterprise**?

For example: I want all emails coming from **john@example.com** to be forwarded to **pavel@myenterprise.com**

Default routing doesn't seem to be the option I'm looking for.

Would appreciate any kind of help I can get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use default routing to act as a catch all for different domains. This rule should accomplish what you want.

1. Specify envelope recipients to match:

   - Pattern match: **john@example\.com**
2. If the envelope recipient matches the above, do the following

   - Headers

     1. Optionally add the *X-Gm-Original-To* header.
   - Modify message

     1. Subject: Prepend custom subject. I use this to test the rule.
     2. Envelope recipient:

        - Replace recipient: **pavel@myenterprise.com**
3. Options

   - Perform this action on non-recognized and recognized addresses.

To see the route in action, go to Reports > Email Log Search (bottom of menu on left) and search for your email. Expand the sections to see how the email flowed through the system.

I use a similar rule to send all external email sent to a domain (sub-organization in G Suite) to an external gmail account.